# App Crashing in release mode at launch Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on android app and deploying on device n **Release Mode** when I'm executing app **crashing** instantly at launch while the same working in **Debug Mode**. What causes an issue? is there anything that I need to follow while building in release mode?

> It says App MyAppName has stopped working unfortunately.

Comment: debug your app and tell us the line that makes the crash happen, you can also try upgrading to a beta/alpha release of xamarin if you are using xamarins tudio to check if the problem is with the studio

Comment: Thank you @CDrosos but I cant debug app in release mode and yeah It seems problem in XS. RIYAZ solution work for me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly issue it is, but I got workaround for this issue; to make it working you must delete your working app package from the following location:

> File Manager > Android > Data > com.YourAppPackage.droid

[image: Delete Package]

After delete your exist package try to execute your app again. Hope It start rolling.

Cheers!!